# How to solve a complex MySQL query to show the name of two users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

One table is called "users" and another table is called "assessment_submissions".

The "users" table contains an "id" and a "name" parameter.

The "assessment_submissions" contains an "evaluator_user" parameter and "evaluated_user" parameter, both parameters are related to the users id on the first table.

When I execute the following SQL query:

```
select * from assessment_submissions
join users
on assessment_submissions.evaluator_user = users.id 
where evaluated_user = 6 and evaluator_user = 3
limit 1
```

The query above gives me the name of the "evaluator_user", but I want to create a SQL query that gives me the name of the "evaluated_user " and the "evaluator_user " in the same row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the submission list to the user list twice to get both users

```
SELECT 
    submission.id,
    evaluator.name,
    evaluated.name 
FROM 
    assessment_submissions AS submission
LEFT JOIN
    user AS evaluator
ON
    submission.evaluator_user = evaluator.id
LEFT JOIN
    user AS evaluated
ON
    submission.evaluated_user = evaluated.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Join users a second time with another alias.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    as_sub.id, u1.name, u2.name 
FROM 
    assessment_submissions as_sub, 
    users u1, 
    users u2 
WHERE 
    u1.id = as_sub.evaluator_user and 
    u2.id = as_sub.evaluated_user
```